# Magnetic flux through the torroid

Tags: electromagnetism

I am trying to derive the magnetic flux through a toroid of inner radius $\rho_0$ and outer radius $\rho_0 + 2a$, having $N$ turns

I started off, by saying $$\phi = \int \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dS}$$

We know that $$\vec{B}   = \mu_0\frac{n}{2\pi\rho_0}I  \vec{a_\phi} $$

What should I choose $dS$ as ?

dS should be the area element between the loops of the wire wound around the toroid ? (Am I right in saying this ?)

The answer is $$ \phi = \mu_0 NI[\rho_0 - (\rho_0^2 -a^2 )^{1/2}]$$

Can you please guide me through this problem

Thank YOu very much

Anupam

Answer (score 1):

There are detailed discussions of this problem in most E&M texts, including Griffith and Jackson.

The easiest way to approach the problem is using Ampere's Law, with an Amperian loop through the center of the toroid, as seen [here](http://www.phys.uri.edu/gerhard/PHY204/tsl242.pdf).

We know that $$\int B \cdot dS = \mu I_{inc}$$

and the current enclosed by that particular loop is just the number of loops $N$ times the current through the wire. So the equality becomes $$\int B \cdot dS = \mu I N$$

and from the Biot Savart law, we know that the magnetic field through the center of the toroid is constant and circumferential. So this in turn becomes $$2\pi R B = \mu I N$$

which simplifies to $$B = \frac{\mu I N}{2\pi R}$$

There are a lot of assumptions made in this calculation, so the Biot Savart approach can be more satisfying. Try with a straight solenoid first, and then curve it. Parameterize the solenoid $$\langle{rcos(\theta),rsin(\theta),k\theta}\rangle$$

and then take the cross product of the derivative with the vector to get the vertical component, and then take a further dot product with $(0,0,1)$ to get the vertical component.

Hope this helps.